# MVC Nested View Model properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having an issue with properties being mapped from my View Model, to a nested View Model. My structure (slimmed down):

**ViewModels:**

```
public class PolicyViewModel
{
     public int PolicyId { get; set; }
     public NoteViewModel NoteVM { get; set; }
}

public class NoteViewModel
{
     public int PolicyId { get; set; }
}
```

**Policy Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Adjustment(int policyId = 0, int historyId = 0)
{
    GroupPolicyViewModel groupPolicyVM = new GroupPolicyViewModel();
    // Automap all property values, then assign the policy Id to the nested controller?!
    groupPolicyVM.NoteVM = new NoteViewModel { PolicyId = policyId };

    return View(groupPolicyVM);
}
```

**Note Controller**

```
public int PolicyId { get; set; } // null
public JsonResult Get(int take, int skip, FilterExpression filter, NoteViewModel NoteVM)
{
     // How do I get the PolicyId here?! NoteVM PolicyId is null
     // This function is being called via jQuery from the Policy form and I obviously don't want to send the policyId via QueryString.

}
```

**View**
And, of course, in my View I have:

```
@Html.Partial("_Notes", Model.NoteVM)

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PolicyId)

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NoteVM.PolicyId) // also tried this with no success!
```

I guess this should be a pretty popular thing to do, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas? I'm doing it this way as I'll need the Note partial view for multiple pages.

Comment: i don't know how you are calling Get method, in your code you are calling @Html.Partial("_Notes", Model.NoteVM), secondly you need to use return view(); in Adjustment action.

Comment: The Get method is called via Ajax on the Policy form (I should have mentioned that, it could be part of the problem). And I am returning View() in the Adjustment section, with the Policy ViewModel.

Comment: 1) try sending policyId in separately as you send take,skip, it will confirm you that you have the data value. (2) check your ajax calling code, when you build the NoteViewModel for sending it, have you set value there.

Comment: Yep, I did that and that works, but that'll be sending the PolicyId via QueryString in the AJAX call, which I don't really want to do due for security reasons.

Comment: So you are ok with PolicyId being in the HTML source as a hidden field, but NOT ok with it being in a query string? That seems strange to me. Are you trying to hide the PolicyId from the current user, or from folks somehow monitoring their traffic?